# What is the difference between \maketitle and \titlepage in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I am looking for someone who has read the lengthy Beamer manual.

Using `\maketitle`

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

versus using `\titlepage`

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What is the difference between `\maketitle` and `\titlepage` in Beamer?

Comment: You *did* read page 93 of the manual, didn't you?

Comment: @lockstep: I have not read the manual. I am a pragmatist who learns by example first.

Comment: It's quite pragmatic to read the manual.

Comment: no, you are searching for one who had read the manual ...

Comment: @Herbert: Yes. This is the correct comment.

Comment: @percusse: 247-page manual is too heavy for pragmatists to grasp its contents at a glance.

Comment: One could open the PDF, search for "\maketitle" and arrive at page 93 straight away.

Comment: @lockstep: When this question came to my mind, I immediately look for it using google.  [But the results on the first page are unsatisfactory](https://isearch.avg.com/search?q=beamer+maketitle&sap=nt&lang=en&mid=872a4d41de3d47d098b7d15dc312a701-06ce4fc639803a2e3563922518183d8e94088cb9&cid=%7B9C4EC3A8-F4FF-48D8-925D-7C64731CE2FC%7D&v=12.2.0.5&ds=gm011&d=8%2F17%2F2012+1%3A02%3A03+PM&pr=sa&snd=hp).

Comment: stop mentioning manuals, it's all about google and stackexchange now!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `beamerbasetitle.sty` one finds

```
%
%
% The \maketitle command (for compatibility with other classes)
%
%
\def\maketitle{\ifbeamer@inframe\titlepage\else\frame{\titlepage}\fi}
```

and

```
\def\titlepage{\usebeamertemplate*{title page}\@thanks}
```

so `\maketitle` is basically `\titlepage` but adding a `\frame` if necessary, and it is provided for compatibility.

Comment: One thing perhaps worth noting is that `\maketitle` outside a frame is ignored if the `ignorenonframetext` option is set since it is not *explicitly* inside a frame.

Answer (score 7):

Only the second one allow you to use `\includeonlyframes{current}` keeping the title.

```
\begin{frame}[label=current]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.